# Meaning of "twos and ones and ones and twos"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I'm trying to translate an episode of a TV series and one of the characters says the following, while moving pieces on a chessboard:

> He taught us twos and ones and ones and twos when it comes to
> planning your battle and executing it perfectly with the disciplines
> of the war.

The above is from the transcript but I also hear the following, I don't know which one is correct:

> **It's all just** twos and ones and ones and twos when it comes to
> planning your battle and executing it perfectly with the disciplines
> of the war.

What would be the meaning of "twos and ones and ones and twos"?

My idea was first to think it meant "he taught us everything" but it does not really seem fitting.
So I thought it could be about placement of people, in groups or alone, to use in the battle plan.
Then, the second possibility with "it's all just" feels also more fitting with "managing the use of people".

I can't find much about this expression so I hope somebody will be able to shed some light.

Here is a link to the transcript of the episode (I couldn't find a video online): https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=557&t=50984

Comment: The exact sequence **twos and ones and ones and twos** doesn't even occur *once* in all the millions of books indexed in Google Books. And it only gets 3 hits on the entire Internet (Google obviously hasn't *yet* indexed this new ELU question itself! :) The collocation obviously has no *established* meaning, so it's basically a matter of opinion (plus knowledge of the *exact* context, which I don't have).

Comment: Yes, I found almost nothing about it and was worried it might be something made up for the character of the show ... I think "the ABCs" represents well my first idea and the "small numver or groups" my second idea. I guess I'll have to choose one and go with it.

Comment: It sounds as if it means "the logic".

Comment: Possibly: In a fight a one two punch is a two-punch combination designed to knockout your opponent.  Not sure about the twos and ones though.

Comment: It might be a description of how the knight moves.  / You should provide a link and the name of the series and episode number.

Comment: @aparente001, this is a very good point! I think you are right about the knight moves! Here is the link, though I couldn't find the video online: https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=557&t=50984

Comment: Also provide a bit more context, like the couple sentences previous. I've never heard this before, and it seems that google hasn't either. It could be the author making it up (reasonably) or it could be an old saying that has been paraphrased in a new way, or most anything.

Comment: Wait...don't bother... I looked at the transcript and none of it makes sense, or rather it probably makes sense if you watch the show in video, but the transcript doesn't say who says what.

Comment: Maybe it's inscrutable even for native speakers? Not everything means something. People aren't perfect and aren't perfect at expressing themselves, even writers. So don't worry about it, don't try to remember it, worry more about ... I don't know... nuanced differences among synonyms?

Comment: He has a Welsh accent which may be why you hear something different to the transcript (which is correct). In terms of the actual sentence; as he is playing Chess, I would equate it to the movement of pawns which can move either one or two spaces from their starting positions, which to me would imply considering the order of movements of troops. I think it is supposed to be an idiosyncratic sentence to go with what I can see is an odd character, and likely has no real basis.

Comment: @Tragamor - good idea, the options for moving pawns.

Comment: I wonder if it actually refers to knights, which move 2 spaces in one direction and 1 space in the other.

Comment: @Tragamor, that was a very good point! That added to an earlier comment about the knight moves make me think we got the answer. Unfortunately, this is very hard to convey in another language but that's besides the point ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I agree that this is most likely the meaning behind this.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a better Answer than Barmar's knight moves in chess, though even that much I've never noticed in 60 years of listening. 

Either way, who believes '… when it comes to planning your battle and executing it perfectly with the disciplines of the war…' is natural English?